# Using fetchrow_hashref to store data

Tags: mysql, perl, hash

I am trying to take information out of a MySQL database, which I will then manipulate in perl:

```
use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbh_m= DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:Populationdb","root","LisaUni") 
or die("Error: $DBI::errstr");

my $Genotype = 'Genotype'.1;
#The idea here is eventually I will ask the database how many Genotypes there are, and then loop it round to complete the following for each Genotype:

my $sql =qq(SELECT TransNo, gene.Gene FROM gene JOIN genotypegene ON gene.Gene =       genotypegene.Gene WHERE Genotype like '$Genotype');
my $sth = $dbh_m-> prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;

my %hash;

my $transvalues = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
my %hash= %$transvalues;

$sth ->finish();
$dbh_m->disconnect();       

my $key;
my $value;

while (($key, $value) = each(%hash)){
 print $key.", ".$value\n; }
```

This code doesn't produce any errors, but the %hash only stores the last row taken from the database (I got the idea of writing it this way from [this website](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=194072)). If I type:

```
while(my $transvalues = $sth->fetchrow_hashref){
print "Gene: $transvalues->{Gene}\n";
print "Trans: $transvalues->{TransNo}\n";
}
```

Then it does print off all the rows, but I need all this information to be available once I've closed the connection to the database.

I also have a related question: in my MySQL database the row consists of e.g 'Gene1'(Gene) '4'(TransNo). Once I have taken this data out of the database as I am doing above, will the TransNo still know which Gene it is associated with? Or do I need to create some kind of hash of hash structure for that?

Comment: One side note on your SQL statement in Perl, you can take the variable out of your $sql variable and include as part of the execute statement.  Try this:
`my $sql =qq(SELECT ... WHERE Genotype like ?);
my $sth = $dbh_m-> prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($Genotype);`
This will prevent against SQL injection attacks and is a good practice to get into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You are calling the "wrong" function

`fetchrow_hashref` will return **one** row as a hashref, you should wrap it's use inside a loop, ending it when `fetchrow_hashref` returns *`undef`*.

It seems like you are looking for **`fetchall_hashref`**, that will give you all of the returned rows as a hash with the first parameter specified what field to use as a key.

```
$hash_ref = $sth->fetchall_hashref ($key_field);
```

Each row will be inserted into `$hash_ref` as an internal hashref, using `$key_field` as the key in which you can find the row in `$hash_ref`.

#### What does the documentation say?

> The fetchall_hashref method can be used to fetch all the data to be returned from a prepared and executed statement handle.
>
> It returns a reference to a hash containing a key for each distinct value of the $key_field column that was fetched.
>
> For each key the corresponding value is a reference to a hash containing all the selected columns and their values, as returned by fetchrow_hashref().

---

#### Documentation links

- [DBI - search.cpan.org #fetchrow_hashref](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#fetchrow_hashref)
- [DBI - search.cpan.org #fetchall_hashref](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#fetchall_hashref)

Comment: Thank you - I have now changed it to:
    my $transvalues = $sth->fetchall_hashref('Gene');
    print $transvalues->{Gene1}->{TransNo}
How would I loop this so it prints all the genes?

Comment: By.. creating a loop that iterates over the hashref, you pretty much answered the question, with the question. Sample http://codepad.org/31SEnbYs (also, please accept the answer to mark the question as solved)